# Как остановить контейнер podman?

Tags: docker

Не получается остановить и удалить контейнер podman.
Если я его удаляю, то из-за conmon, он снова запускается.

Пробовал удалить scope unit, который запускал данный контейнер, и удачно остановленный контейнер удалялся с помощью conmon и с новым юнитом снова запускался.

Comment: Вы запускаете через docker-compose или через docker?

Comment: @instahipsta282 docker не установлен в системе. Вообще этот контейнер создался во время установки ceph https://github.com/ceph/ceph-ansible

Comment: скорее всего внутри прописано что-то типа "restart: always" - при такой настройке docker поднимает контейнер при каждом входе в систему автоматически, насколько я знаю.

Comment: @instahipsta282 да, так оно и есть. В итоге это не conmon, а unit script, который запускает контейнер и у него прописано restart: always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел systemctl юнит, который запускал скрипт, в котором было прописано всегда запускать контейнер.